# как получить EditText из AlertDialog

Tags: android

не могу получить `EditText` из `AlertDialog`, помогите[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам наверное нужно получить не сам виджет, а его содержимое (то, что в него ввели)? Прежде чем задать вопрос, ознакомтесь как здесь [задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ.

Comment: да мне нужно его содержимое

Comment: Где вам нужно его содержимое, что из себя представляет AlertDialog. Код диалога и откуда он вызывается, а не картинки

Comment: @ІванМороз определённо нужен минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

вам необходимо создать свою разметку и подтянуть ее  в диалог, примерно так:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mPositive = savedInstanceState.getString("yes");
        mNegative = savedInstanceState.getString("no");
        mTitle = savedInstanceState.getString("title");
    }
    Context dialogViewContext = getActivity();
    View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(dialogViewContext)
            .inflate(R.layout.simple_dialog, null);
    final TextInputEditText editText = (TextInputEditText) dialogView
            .findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new AddListenerOnTextChange(editText));
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.StyledDialog);
    adb.setView(dialogView);
    adb.setCancelable(false);
    adb.setTitle(mTitle);
    adb.setPositiveButton(mPositive, mDialogInterfaceListener);
    adb.setNegativeButton(mNegative, mDialogInterfaceListener);
    return adb.create();
}
```

Далее регистрируете нужные вьюшки и вешаете на них листенеры. и Обрабатываете результат в листенере:

```
public class AddListenerOnTextChange implements TextWatcher {
    private View mView;

    public AddListenerOnTextChange(View view) {
        this.mView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        switch (mView.getId()) {
            case R.id.edit_text:
               //тут получаете результат
                break;
        }
    }
}
```