# NullPointerException при вызове EditText.getText()

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

```
public void foodbuttonclick(View view) {
    final EditText foodtext;
    final TextView textView2;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    foodtext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.input_text);
    builder.setTitle("Еда")
        .setMessage("Введите сумму:")
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setView(dialog_view)
        .setNegativeButton("Подтведрить",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    String foodstr = foodtext.getText().toString();
                    //String foodstr = (String.valueOf(foodint));
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    textView2.setText(foodstr);
                }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

> NullPointerException Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null
>   object reference
>   AndroidStudio пишет, что проблема
>   com.example.andrew.moneysaver.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:94) в строке String foodstr = foodtext.getText().toString();

Comment: как вам уже и сказали, вы не там ищите `EditText`/ Вы пытаетесь найти его в кнопке, по которой кликнули (его там, естественно, нет), а надо искать в разметке, назначенной методом `setView()` - `dialog_view`/ Смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/642999/177345) и обратите внимание к какому объекту применяется метод `findViewById()`. PS: имена объектов класса пишутся с маленькой буквы в camalCase стиле (`dialogView`), а не через подчеркивание, которое используется в именовании разметки.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не там его ищете:

```
    view.findViewById(R.id.input_text);
```

- ведь `view` это кнопка, на которую нажали, а `EditText` видимо в `dialog_view`.

`findViewById` нужно вызывать у `view`, в которая содержит искомый элемент:

```
textView2 = (TextView) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
foodtext = (EditText) dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.input_text);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, EditText находится в dialog_view.
Но если оставить просто findViewById(id.input_text), то ошибка не меняется.
Не понимаю, почему он считает EditText нулевым объектом (Может, я несознательно, новичок ещё, оставил ссылку, но не понимаю, где именно)

Comment: Если оставить просто `findViewById(id.input_text)` - это будет поиск в разметке текущей `Activity`. А Вам нужен диалог. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Понял, что вы имеете ввиду, большое спасибо. Но сейчас Android Studio не нравится метод findViewById (Can't resolve method).
И он предлагает добавить вместо обозначения нужного мне места "view", "foodtext" или "textView2".
Простите, просто хочу разобраться, чтобы в дальнейшем не допускать таких(уверен, глупых) ошибок

Comment: Так `dialog_view` - это id  разметки? Тогда Вам нужно сначала создать `View` и уже из неё доставать нужные элементы. Пройдите по ссылке в комменте pavlofff'а там как раз это проиллюстрировано

Comment: Метод findViewById принадлежит классам `View` и `Activity` - соответственно вызван он может быть только у объектов этих классов и их потомков.

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.promt, null);
final EditText userInput = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.input_text);
```

Такой вариант решения проблемы мне помог.